# python multiple inheritance calling overridden functions in super context

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, mixins, super

(Python 3)

I'm trying to extend a class with some fancy new formatting routines, however I'd also like to be able to use the formatting routines in the base class.

```
class Plaintext(object):
    def print_thing(self, thing):
        print("plain", thing)

    def print_blob(self, blob):
        for thing in blob:
            self.print_thing(thing)

    def print_goober(self, blob):
        print("plaintext")
        self.print_blob(blob)

class Markdown(Plaintext):
    def print_thing(self, thing):
        print("mark", thing)

    def print_goober(self, blob):
        print("markdown")
        self.print_blob(blob)
        super().print_blob(blob)

newclass = Markdown()
newclass.print_goober([1,2,3])
```

When run, I get:

```
markdown
mark 1
mark 2
mark 3
mark 1
mark 2
mark 3
```

How can I get newclass.print_goober() to call print_blob() first in its self context and then in the context of BaseClass?

The output I was trying to get was:

```
markdown
mark 1
mark 2
mark 3
plain 1
plain 2
plain 3
```

Do I need to create some sort of mixin thing?

Comment: Your `print_thing()` method is being overridden in the sub-class. That's why it's printing all `mark`s

Comment: syntax for calling super is wrong. It should be ```super(Markdown, self).print_blob(blob)```

Comment: @naveenyadav -- The no argument `super()` shortcut form was introduced in python3.x.

Comment: I understand that print_thing() is being overridden.  However, I want to be able to call print_blob in the context where print_thing() would NOT be overridden.  print_blob is a large and complex function, so point was to not duplicate the code just to override one tiny thing to support markdown.

Comment: @PaulT. -- Python supports name mangling for names that are prefixed by `__` -- e.g. `__name`.  The interpreter actually changes names like that to `_classname__name`. The problem is that it makes it hard for subclasses to call `__name` (unless you do the name mangling yourself -- which is definitely a hack).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... `self` is well ... `self`.  In your example, every time you call `self`, it *is* the instance of `Markdown` that is known on the outside as `newclass`.

When you think of it this way, `self.print_thing` does what you would expect it to.  It looks for the first `print_thing` method it can find and then calls it with `self` as the first argument.

Alright, now that we have that sorted ... How do we do what you want to do?  Well, (and I can't say this strongly enough) there's no *clean* way to do it without being more explicit about what you actually want.  In this case, I'd recommend having `markdown` define new methods that call the old ones:

```
class Plaintext(object):
    def print_thing(self, thing):
        print("plain", thing)

    def print_blob(self, blob):
        for thing in blob:
            self.print_thing(thing)

    def print_goober(self, blob):
        print("plaintext")
        self.print_blob(blob)

class Markdown(Plaintext):
    def print_markdown_thing(self, thing):
        print("mark", thing)

    def print_markdown_blob(self, blob):
        for thing in blob:
            self.print_markdown_thing(thing)

    def print_goober(self, blob):
        print("markdown")
        self.print_markdown_blob(blob)
        self.print_blob(blob)

newclass = Markdown()
newclass.print_goober([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to avoid that, as print_blob() is a complex routine and would involve code replication.